# Is there a way to find iPhone IMEI number before phone arrives?

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I want to buy iPhone 14 Pro in Germany but  i need to learn phone IMEI number to save that number for taxes in my country before new year (to pay much less).

Is there a way(customer service, apple website etc.) to learn it after order before it's delivered?

Comment: In which country will you be purchasing the phone? It's highly likely a carrier or store making the sale could assist you with this, but we just have to guess a ton about your situation to help

Comment: My friend gonna buy for me from germany. I think the phone was made in asia and it takes time to come where you order. She will order to Dresden, Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your friend buys it, have her send you a photo of the label on the outside of the box.  It has the model number, serial number, IMEI, and other things.

If buying online, I don't think Apple puts that information in the invoice.  I know things I've bought, I get an e-mail that does not have any of that.

Comment: Actually online buying cause of that i am dealing with this trouble :(